# Pixlr API integration

Tags: javascript, html, pixlr

I am trying to integrate pixlr API into my website with the little documentation they give you on their site. When I click on an image to load the image editor it says The page you were looking for doesn't exist. Any ideas why I might be getting this? Here is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Designer Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pixlr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        pixlr.settings.target = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/designer/php/savefile.php';
        pixlr.settings.exit = 'http://xxxxxx.com/designer';
        pixlr.settings.method = 'post';
        pixlr.settings.locktarget = true;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Click the image to edit</h4>
<br />
<b>Open image editor overlay</b><br />
<a href="javascript:pixlr.overlay.show({image:'http://xxxxxxx.com/designer/images/roofCrafters.png', title:'Roof Crafters'});"><img src="images/roofCrafters.png" width="250" height="150" title="Edit in pixlr" /></a><br /><br />
<br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with 
`javascript:pixlr.overlay.show({image:'images/roofCrafters.png', title:'Roof Crafters'});`?

Comment: Also, does http://xxxxxxx.com/designer/php/savefile.php exist?

Comment: yes that file does exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the service you want to use in your url, for example :

```
<a href="javascript:pixlr.overlay.show({image:'http://xxxxxxx.com/designer/images/roofCrafters.png', title:'Roof Crafters', service:'editor'});">
```

You can use 'editor' or 'express'